# Setting the position of the soft keybaord in android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, ime

I am wondering if there is any way to set the position of the soft keyboard in android? I have a toolbar at the bottom which i want to remain visible when the keyboard appears. So is there any way of positioning the soft keyboard above the toolbar on screen? I have tried using different layouts but the keyboard always appears from the bottom of the screen hiding the toolbar.

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: I have the same problem. I did some investigating and this article shows that the virtual keyboard always scrolls up from the bottom: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way to set the position of the soft keyboard, what you can do is put all of the content in a `ScrollView` except the toolbar and making the toolbar appear above the keyboard